# Uploading File in Azure using CLI

Tags: azure

I am trying to practice on the following tasks:

1. Create Storage Account:
   az storage account create --name heyatafroz25 --resource-group user-fottsascvuzj
2. Get Storage Account Key:
   az storage account keys list -g user-fottsascvuzj -n heyatafroz25
3. Create Share Account:
   az storage share create --account-name heyatafroz25 --name key1
   az storage share create --account-name heyatafroz25 --name key2
4. Create Storage Directory:
   az storage directory create --account-name heyatafroz25 --name heyatdir1 --share-name key1
   az storage directory create --account-name heyatafroz25 --name heyatdir2 --share-name key2
5. Uploading the File

I was asked to create a index.php file which i created using the touch command.

Post that I am not sure what details to be considered for path and source.
For path i took the present working directory

az storage file upload --account-name heyatafroz25 --account-key {ACCOUNT_KEY} --path /home/scrapbook/tutorial/index.php --share-name key1 --source /home/scrapbook/tutorial/index.php

Please suggest on the corrections in the 5th command.

Comment: You can make your questions easier to understand if you take the time to format them.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the documentation for [`az storage file upload`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/file?view=azure-cli-latest#az-storage-file-upload):

**--source: Path of the local file to upload as the file content.**

Essentially this is the path of the local file you want to upload.

**--path: The path to the file within the file share. If the file name is omitted, the source file name will be used.**

So assuming if you're uploading a file, it would be the name of the file you want the local file to be saved in the storage.

To elaborate further, let's say you have a local file called "image.png" and you want to save it as "logo.png", you will use the following command:

```
az storage file upload --account-name <account-name> --account-key <account-key> --share-name <share-name> --path logo.png --source image.png
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed understanding along with the example. Will try and update on that...Thank  you very much

Answer (score 3):

Try running the following command:

```
az storage file upload --account-name mystorageaccount --account-key myaccountkey --share-name myfileshare --path "myDirectory/index.php" --source "/home/scrapbook/tutorial/php-docs-hello-world/index.php"
```